# Where can I find the setting for folding / unfolding the import statements in java in eclipse by default

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to find the setting in Eclipse where I can have the import block in java expanded by default?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is under Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Folding